# Converter/Formatted method Not Work Perfectly After JDK version change to 8 to 12

Tags: java, spring

recently i change jdk version 8 to 12 in my sprint web application. application run ok but converter/Formatted related method return unexpected result.

problem example: input data .007 to format in 2 decimal places. but output found .০১

Comment: Officially Spring doesn't support JDK12 yet. 5.2 has been tested with it, but that isn't final. Anything before that doesn't support it. The 5.1 version supports Java 11 every version before that only Java8 (officially)